# Conjugacy classes of a quotient group

Tags: group-theory, inequality, finite-groups, normal-subgroups, quotient-group

Let $G$ be a finite group and let $N$ be a normal subgroup of $G$. Let $c(H)$ denote the number of conjugacy classes of a finite group $H$.

(a) Is it true that $c(G)\leq c(N)c(G/N)$?

(b) When does equality hold?

(c) Is the ratio $c(N)c(G/N)/c(G)$ always an integer?

This question can also be phrased in terms of a short exact sequence of finite groups
$$1\longrightarrow N\longrightarrow G\longrightarrow K\longrightarrow1.$$
If this short exact sequence is isomorphic to $1\to N\to N\times K\to K\to1$ then it can be shown that $c(G)=c(N)c(K)$. However, even if the short exact sequence splits (meaning that the short exact sequence is isomorphic to $1\to N\to N\rtimes K\to K\to1$), it might not be the case that $c(G)=c(N)c(K)$. For instance, $N$ and $K$ might both be abelian while $G$ is nonabelian.

Comment: If $G$ is the direct product of $N$ and $G/N$ then $c(G)=c(N)c(G/N)$.

Comment: Yes, a) is true. See [this](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.ojm/1353055010)

Comment: The answer to c) is no. For example, $c(D_8)=5$. I am not sure about b).

Comment: I don't understand the votes to close. Could someone explain?